# Parent container with percentage min-height, child container with percentage height, not working

Tags: css

Basically, I gave the parent container a min-height of 50%, and the child container a height of 50%. I put lots of text inside the parent container, so it will expand say to 60%. I tried the height: 1px trick. It did not work. Basically the child container remains at 50% of parent's min-height (i.e. 50%) instead of 50% of the parent's actual height (e.g. 60%).

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#parent {
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  min-height: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#child {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  dsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf
  sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds sddfsdsds dsfdsf sdffds
  <div id="child">
    Hello World!
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

An application of this is to create a full page div that is allowed to grow when there is an overflow (i.e. min-height 100%). This full page div can contain a child container (e.g. a non-absolute or fixed header) with percentage height as described in the scenario above.

Comment: Because the `height` of your `#child` is actually _adding_ to the height of the parent, it will not display as `50%` as otherwise the parent would grow, then the child would have to grow, and so on forever (or until an eventual memory problem - `height = 50% * (parentHeight + height)` is not solvable as it is _recursive_). This only works if you place the item at a `position` other than `relative`, which is not what you're looking for. The solution here can probably only be javascript based, but again, your `#child` should have a `height` of 0 in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this for a simply reason: your `#child` is actually *expanding* your parent - it is part of the content. You might notice that if you give your parent a `relative` height, and the child an `absolute` height, the `50%`*does* work. But that is because your content has been taken out of regular flow.

The simply logical reason you can use to justify this behaviour is to try and solve it mathematically. Let's say we have `p`, which is the parents height, and `e` which is the height of the content other than the child. That makes `c` the child height, or `h / 2`. The equation to calculate the Child height would therefor be:

```
var c = (e + c) / 2
```

Which you cannot solve, as it turns into this:

```
var c = (e + (e + (e + (e + ... ) / 2) / 2) / 2) / 2
```

Which, if the `...` doesn't tell you, is unsolvable.

**This problem cannot be alleviated without breaking from the regular flow and making your size relative to something that can be calculated.**

Comment: Thanks. But the equation looks solvable?
`c = (e+c)/2 => c=e`. Intuitively, the browser should grow `e` and `c` equally until `e+c` greater than the parent's min-height, in this case height of window. If there are no overflow `c+e= window height` otherwise `c+e > window height`.

Comment: Hmm yeah. Bad example, but the essential problem is the same. How can you know what 50% is when it adds to your parents height? Thats unsolvable. I will amend when i get a chance. Also, growing until the windowsheight means the positioning of the browser has to change.

Comment: Okay, I think I see your point. But it will not grow indefinitely if the browser pick the smallest size that will satisfy the condition, similar to fitting a div to inline elements.